# How to use updated version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

On my Mac (I'm a Windows user), I'm trying to update Ruby. So I did it with Homebrew, and when I write

```
brew update ruby
```

it says

```
ruby 2.5.3 already installed
```

but typing

```
ruby -v
```

in the terminal produces:

```
Error: ruby 2.5.3 already installed
```

I'd guess it's a `PATH` variable that's not being pointed to? Why are there more than one installations of Ruby? How do I correct this to use the Homebrew version?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use https://rvm.io

Comment: What you're reporting seems dubious.  `brew update ruby` produces the message `Error: This command updates brew itself, and does not take formula names.
Use 'brew upgrade ruby' instead.`  In other words, the error you're reporting is not consistent with `brew update`'s behavior and is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

using:

```
brew link --overwrite ruby
```

and restarting terminal worked.

Comment: Like @iGian commented above, you will be much, much better off if you install Ruby on macOS with [RVM](https://rvm.io/). The default version of Ruby and versions installed by brew lead to all kinds of issues, and troubleshooting them is a nightmare. Asking for help in the future will lead to people telling you not to use them and to use RVM instead. (or rbenv)